# Moment Generating function proof

Tags: statistics

Let X have moment generating function M(t), and let v(t)=lnM(t).  show that v'(0)=E(X) and v''(0)=Var(X).

I know the formula's for E(X) and Var(X), but don't I need an original pdf of X to compute the expected value and variance?  How would I show these are equal without an original equation or without M(t)?

Comment: Do you know formulas for the expected value and variance in terms of the moment generating function?

Comment: No, just their formulas when given a pdf

Comment: well, I'm pretty sure that's what this problem is going for. Specifically, $E(X) = M'(0)$ and $E(X^2) = M''(0)$.

Comment: And the variance can be given in terms of $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$.

Comment: right, what I'm asking is how I prove this when I am not given a pdf? Don't I need a pdf so I can do the calculations to show what E(X) is and Var(X) is, and then calculate through the mgf that M'(0) is the same as E(X) and M''(0) is the same as Var(X)?

Comment: If you really feel the need to start from first principles, call your pdf $f$.  Now you have a pdf you can do the MGF transform on.  This is a good question, by the way.